# `conda search PKG --info` shows different dependencies than what conda wants to install?

Tags: numpy, scipy, conda

I'm building a new conda environment using `python=3.9` for the
`osx-arm64` architecture.

- conda create -n py39 python=3.9 numpy
- conda list

  ```
    ...
    numpy                     1.21.1           py39h1a24bff_2  
    ...
    python                    3.9.7                hc70090a_1
  ```

So far so good: `numpy=1.21.1` is the one i want.  Now I want to add
`scipy`, and the first one seems to fit the bill:

- conda search scipy --info

  ```
    scipy 1.7.1 py39h2f0f56f_2
    --------------------------
    file name   : scipy-1.7.1-py39h2f0f56f_2.conda
    name        : scipy
    version     : 1.7.1
    build       : py39h2f0f56f_2
    build number: 2
    size        : 14.8 MB
    license     : BSD 3-Clause
    subdir      : osx-arm64
    url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/scipy-1.7.1-py39h2f0f56f_2.conda
    md5         : edbd5a5399e973d1d0325147b7118f79
    timestamp   : 2021-08-25 16:12:39 UTC
    dependencies: 
    - blas * openblas
    - libcxx >=12.0.0
    - libgfortran 5.*
    - libgfortran5 >=11.1.0
    - libopenblas >=0.3.17,<1.0a0
    - numpy >=1.19.5,<2.0a0
    - python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0
  ```

in particular, `python >=3.9` and `numpy >=1.19` seems just right.
but when i try the install

- conda install scipy

  ```
    ...
    The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    numpy                               1.21.1-py39h1a24bff_2 --> 1.19.5-py39habd9f23_3
  ```

(I have bumped into various constraints with `numpy=1.19` (numba,
pandas,) and am trying to avoid it.)

*Why isn't the scipy package happy with the `numpy=1.21` version I
have?!*

The only possible clue is that conda reports a *different python
version* (3.8.11) than the v3.9 I specified for this environment:

- conda info

  active environment : py39
  active env location : .../miniconda3/envs/py39
  shell level : 1
  user config file : .../.condarc
  populated config files : .../.condarc
  conda version : 4.11.0
  conda-build version : not installed
  python version : 3.8.11.final.0                  <-------------------
  virtual packages : __osx=12.1=0
  ...

but all the environment's pointers seem to be set correctly:

- (py39) % which python

  .../miniconda3/envs/py39/bin/python
- (py39)  % python

  Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 23:53:23)
  [Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

Thanks, any hints as to what's broken will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `conda info` Python version is for the **base** environment, not the active one. Would be more insightful to specify what you want, then get back why it fails, e.g., `mamba create -n foo python=3.9.7 numpy=1.21.1 scipy=1.7.1` (Using mamba for this because conda has terrible conflict diagnostic reporting)

Comment: thanks @merv! i have had an incremental approach, but your all-in-one approach `conda create -n scipy python=3.9.7 numpy=1.21.1 scipy=1.7.1` gives a clear statement of the conflicts: 
        Package python conflicts for:
  python=3.9.7
  numpy=1.21.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
  scipy=1.7.1 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

  Package numpy conflicts for:
  scipy=1.7.1 -> numpy[version='>=1.19.5,<2.0a0']
  numpy=1.21.1

Comment: Try using `-c conda-forge`. With `mamba` that seems to solve fine (see [simulated run](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/runs/4676271982?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:3)).

Comment: Your simulated run is MacOS=11.6.2; i'm using Monterey (v12.1)

Comment: I added `CONDA_OVERRIDE_OSX=12.1` (mimic Monterey) and included a `conda create` to ensure identical behavior: [still solves fine](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/runs/4696926385?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:3). Unless you are seeing a conflict message involving the [virtual package](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-virtual.html#managing-virtual-packages) `__osx`, it is unlikely that the MacOS version is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I now have things working, but I'm afraid I can't point to a satisfying "answer."  Others (eg @merv) seem to not be having the same problems and I can't identify the difference.

The one thing that I did find that seemed to create issues in my install was what seems to be some mislabeling of the `pandas` package: pandas v1.3.5 breaks a numpy==1.19.5 requirement that is the only way i've been able to push it thru.  i posted a  [pandas issue comment](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45077#issuecomment-1006936428)